# Open browser window on dual monitors

Tags: windows-7, script

My client has dual monitors which they use to display two different websites in a public space. They want to be able to hard reboot the system and have it automatically start two browser windows, one on each monitor, and go to the appropriate websites.

We can get the browsers to start easily enough using the startup folder, but have not been able to figure out how to get one browser window to go to one screen, and the other window to the other screen automatically. Is there a way of doing this in powershell, or some other scripting language?

We are running Windows with IE, but also have Firefox installed.

Comment: The title of the proposed duplicate is similar, but it is not useful.  The upvoted answer is a vague mention that a solution should be possible, but does not provide a solution.  The other answer is link-only, and the links talk about using multiple monitors, also not a solution to this question.  The 5 year-old proposed duplicate has had no activity in 4 years and is not likely to attract new answers.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to open the window and move.

In the documentation is a method called [WinMove](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/WinMove.htm). I think you will need to do some calculation but given it's fixed, it shouldn't be a problem.

A basic example:

```
Run, chrome.exe
WinWait, Chrome
WinMove, 0, 0
```